# LibGDX HTML5 java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException Error

Tags: java, xml, html, gwt, libgdx

While creating a LibGDX app I was trying to get the GWT and HTML5 version to work. While I got the generated basic app working, I tried to get an app that i have been working on for a while working and after updating the ***.gwt.xml file with the locations of the sources I then encountered this error.

```
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.DragAndDrop.Payload
    com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.DragAndDrop.Target
      com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.DragAndDrop.Source
  java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

If you want to read the whole log: http://pastebin.com/NxVKp2eA

I am not sure where to even start finding the source of this error as it seems to be rooted inside libGDX and scene2d if you could enlighten me that would be excellent.

MY HTML ENTRY POINT:

```
package com.mygdx.game.client;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.gwt.GwtApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.gwt.GwtApplicationConfiguration;
import com.nolevelcap.wc.MainWC;

public class HtmlLauncher extends GwtApplication {

        @Override
        public GwtApplicationConfiguration getConfig () {
                return new GwtApplicationConfiguration(1280, 720);
        }

        @Override
        public ApplicationListener getApplicationListener () {
                return new MainWC();
        }
}
```

MY ***.gwt.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit trunk//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>
    <source path="com/nolevelcap/wc" />
    <source path="com/nolevelcap/events" />
    <source path="com/nolevelcap/widget" />
    <source path="com/nolevelcap/utils" />
</module>
```

My GwtDefinition.gwt.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit trunk//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to="html">
    <inherits name='com.badlogic.gdx.backends.gdx_backends_gwt' />
    <inherits name='com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.box2d-gwt' />

    <inherits name='MainWC' />
    <entry-point class='com.mygdx.game.client.HtmlLauncher' />

    <set-configuration-property name="gdx.assetpath" value="../core/assets" />
</module>
```

My GwtDefinitionSuperDev.gwt.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit trunk//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to="html">
    <inherits name='com.badlogic.gdx.backends.gdx_backends_gwt' />
    <inherits name='com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.box2d-gwt' />

    <inherits name='MyTestGame' />
    <entry-point class='com.mygdx.game.client.HtmlLauncher' />

    <add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
    <set-configuration-property name='xsiframe.failIfScriptTag' value='FALSE'/>
    <set-configuration-property name="devModeRedirectEnabled" value="true"/>

    <set-configuration-property name="gdx.assetpath" value="../core/assets" />
</module>
```

Comment: Its not entirely clear to me that your log contains an error.  What behavior do you see?  It can take quite a while for a GWT app to load.

Comment: On chrome I see a LIBGDX loading screen which loads to about 25%.